# Lidgren client joins in editor but not build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lidgren

I'm writing a multiplayer game where multiple clients on their phone should be able to connect to a PC-based server. My editor testing has all worked and the editor client connects fine, I've now built the client project onto my phone and nothing happens when I press to join the server.

Server Creation Method:

```
public void StartServer()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    Debug.Log("Started");
    IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
    Debug.Log(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (IPAddress addr in localIPs)
    {
        if (addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            ip = addr;
        }
    }
    var config = new NetPeerConfiguration("TEC") { Port = 7777, LocalAddress = ip } ;
    config.EnableMessageType(NetIncomingMessageType.ConnectionApproval);
    server = new NetServer(config);
    server.Start();
    Debug.Log("Server Started");
    createButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    serverInfoGroup.SetActive(true);
    ipSlot.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    playerTextSlotsGroup.SetActive(true);
    foreach (var playerSlot in playerTextSlots)
    {
        playerSlot.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    ipSlot.text = Convert.ToString(ip);
```

Client Joining Method:

```
public void JoinServer()
{
    string ip = ipBox.text;
    userName = userBox.text;
    var config = new NetPeerConfiguration("TEC");
    Debug.Log("Connecting with " + ip + " and " + userName);
    client = new NetClient(config);
    client.RegisterReceivedCallback(new SendOrPostCallback(GotMessage));
    client.Start();
    NetOutgoingMessage approval = client.CreateMessage();
    approval.Write("dunno");
    client.Connect(ip, 7777, approval);
    attemptedConnection = true;
    Debug.Log("Server joined");
}
```

JoinServer should be called when a client hits the enter button, the two input boxes are where I enter the IP and username. I have been using the IPv4 address of my computer, gained from the server creation method which the editor can join on, but my phone build not.

I have now tested the program on an android emulator, but the same thing happens, no reaction to the connect to server button.

Comment: And does the ip for your pc start 192 or 172 or 10 or 127?

Comment: 192, my IPv4 Address @BugFinder

Comment: right so thats a local network - if your phone is on wifi it should connect but if its not it cant, 192 isnt routed cos next to every home network is 192.

Comment: @BugFinder my phone is connected through WiFi to the network upon which my PC is wired to, does the wired/wireless difference affect it?

Comment: no but things like windows defender etc and depending on your phone it may not let things connect either..